# How to clear terminal buffer in IntelliJ 2023.1?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently downloaded

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023

In a previous version I used to be able to hit "Ctrl+L" to clear the terminal buffer.  That no longer works.

If you right click in the terminal there is an option menu with an item for
"Clear Buffer  Ctrl+L"
but it is greyed out.

Is there some setting I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to this bug report:
[IDEA-289979](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289979/Windows-Clear-buffer-option-is-disabled)

To fix it:

- Go to Help > Find Action > Registry
- Scroll down till you find `terminal.use.conpty.on.windows`

Make sure the checkbox is unchecked. Click Done.

That's it. Any newly opened terminal will be able to be cleared now.

Comment: For those ending up here: You should (probably) **restart your IDE** for this registry change to take effect.